# Pentaho CDF error : Object type *Component* can't be mapped to a valid class

Tags: javascript, pentaho, pentaho-cde

I migrated Pentaho 7.2 solution to pentaho 8.1 and I get this error when I load page WCDF. Error come from a component execution (it's a grid) created for the old version. Error message in js console :

*CDF : Object type TableWithButtons can't be mapped to a valid class*

The component is open source here : https://github.com/bhericher/TableWithButtons . It was originally designed for pentaho 5.4 and I can modify component source.

I think it's a missing JS class, but where I do create it ?

[image]

Comment: Nobody have same error ?

Answer (score 0):

From pentaho 7.0 onwards some classes are changed in pentaho CDE.

***Instead of Dashboards you have to use Utils method.***

Find below document for more details.

https://help.pentaho.com/Documentation/7.0/0R0/CTools/CDE_Advanced_Solutions